# Использование PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer в XML-конфигурации Spring

Tags: java, xml, spring

есть property файл со следующим содержимым

`client.properties` файл:

```
   id=1
    name=John Smith
    greeting=hello there!
```

Использую его в определении бинов:

```
   <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">

        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:client.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>



 <bean class="Client" id="client">
        <constructor-arg value="${id}"/>
        <constructor-arg value="${name}"/>
 </bean>
```

Теперь я хочу подключить еще 1 property файл с такими же клячами, но разынми значениями

`annotatedClient.properties`:

```
id=2
name=Vasiliy
```

**Как их правильно различать?**

делаю следующим образом:

```
 <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:client.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:annotaitedClient.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
```

так выбрасывается exeption(

> Could not resolve placeholder 'client.id' in string value
>   "${client.id}"

):

```
   <bean class="Client" id="client">
        <constructor-arg value="${client.id}"/>
        <constructor-arg value="${client.name}"/>
     <property name="greeting" value="${greeting}"/>
    </bean>
```

так читается только файл `annotaitedClent.properties`:

```
   <bean class="Client" id="client">
        <constructor-arg value="${id}"/>
        <constructor-arg value="${name}"/>
     <property name="greeting" value="${greeting}"/>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй так:

```
<util:properties id="clientProps" location="classpath:client.properties"></util:properties>
<util:properties id="annotaitedClientProps" location="classpath:annotaitedClient.properties"></util:properties>
<bean id="allProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="propertiesArray">
        <list>
            <ref bean="clientProps"></ref>
            <ref bean="annotaitedClientProps"></ref>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="properties" ref="allProperties"></property>
</bean>
```